# MDX inside / outside a set and alias

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I want to create a set of 2 members : in & out. The first one contains an aggregate of all the user's selection members of a dimension and the second an aggregate of all the others members. I tryed the following :

```
WITH set [ColSet] as
{
   [Lieu].[Societe].members * [Measures].[Mt]
}
set [InitSet] as
{
   [Date].[Annee].[2012],
   [Date].[Annee].[2013]
}
member [RowDim].[in] as aggregate
(
   [InitSet]
)
member [RowDim].[out] as aggregate
(
   except
   (
      [Date].[Annee].members,
      [InitSet]
   )
)
SELECT
NON EMPTY [ColSet] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{
   [RowDim].[in],
   [RowDim].[out]
}
ON ROWS
FROM [Achat]
```

This give me the following result :

```
| C - HYPERS DISTRIBUTION BANANA FRANCE | C - SUPERS DISTRIBUTION BANANA FRANCE | Y - BANANAS  |
| Mt bananas                            | Mt bananas                            | Mt bananas   |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+
|                        764,894,678.51 |                        476,684,988.46 | 2,371,343.76 |
|                         65,479,177.02 |                         41,021,522.71 | 9,374,639.28 |
```

The problem is that I am not able to show the labels "IN" and "OUT" on my row axis. Is there any way of doing this?

I am using Mondrian (3.6.7).

Comment: So you still want the rows of data associated with IN and OUT but you want to hide the labels on the left hand side?

Comment: Actually, with this query, the labels "IN" and "OUT" are hidden. I want to make them visibles but I don't know how.

Comment: try using a different dimension instead of [RowDim] ... you should be able to 'piggy-back' of any of the other dimensions that are not being used in the script

Comment: I just tryed. But I still got no row labels.

Answer (score 0):

Those are appearing "hidden", probably because of the `NON EMPTY` clause. Either you need to get rid of that, or replace a `NULL` with a zero(makes it 'empty' no more), if you want the labels to appear. Try the code below:

```
WITH set [ColSet] as
{
   [Lieu].[Societe].members * [Measures].[Mt]
}
set [InitSet] as
{
   [Date].[Annee].[2012],
   [Date].[Annee].[2013]
}
member  [RowDim].[in] as IIF(ISEMPTY(aggregate
(
   [InitSet]
)) , 0, aggregate
(
   [InitSet]
))
member   [RowDim].[out] as IIF(ISEMPTY(aggregate
(
   except
   (
      [Date].[Annee].members,
      [InitSet]
   ))), 0, aggregate
(
   except
   (
      [Date].[Annee].members,
      [InitSet]
   ))
)
SELECT
NON EMPTY [ColSet] ON COLUMNS,

    {    
    [RowDim].[in],
    [RowDim].[out]
    }
ON ROWS
FROM [Achat]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I edited my question to display the results table. Your query brings me the same result with no row label.